# make a div hide after scrolling and window should scroll to position zero

Tags: javascript

Is that possible to hide a div after scrolling to a certain position and window should scroll to zero.code written as below:

```
<script>    
$(window).scroll(function() {    
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1050){      
    $(".marketing-outer").css("display", "none");                 
    window.scrollTo(0,0);     
  }     
}); 
</script>
```

the script is working fine till the window reaches to zero.but, when we scroll to the same , the window scrolling to zero again .

Comment: What do you mean by every scrolltop?

Comment: Is the problem that you only want this to happen once? So that once the marketing stuff is hidden it doesn't scroll to top again? Because then you just add if(!($".marketing-outer").hasClass('hidden')){//scroll to top and add 'hidden' class} else {//don't scroll to top}